# echarts: bar chart start at value?

Tags: echarts

echarts: bar chart bars are located left and right of the value on the category axis:
[image]

How to tell echarts to start the bar with the value on the category axis? Like this:
[image]

To clarify the problem, here ist another example. This is a chart of the hourly sum of precipitation. Every bar should show the sum from the bottom to the top of the hour, the data values are conencted to every bottom of the hour.
[image]

as you can see, the bars are not starting at 8:00, they are starting at 7:30.

Data: (timestamps are shown in CET)

```
series: [
  {
    name: "Niederschlag",
    type: "bar",
    data: [[1608534000000, 3], [1608537600000, 5], [1608541200000, 2], [1608544800000, 0], [1608548400000, 1] ],
    barWidth: '100%'
  }
]
```

It should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need a hidden xAxis like below:

```
option = {
   xAxis: [{
    type: 'category',
    data: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23],
    show: false
}, {
    type: 'category',
    data: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24],
    boundaryGap: false,
    axisTick: { alignWithLabel: true },
    position: 'bottom'
}],
yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
},
series: [{
    data: [120, 200, 150, 80, 70, 110, 130,120,210,110,210],
    type: 'bar',
    barCategoryGap:'20%',
    itemStyle: {
    },        
    xAxisIndex: 0,
    backgroundStyle: {
        color: 'rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.8)'
    }
}]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Start point of bar here doesn't matter, you need align labels to left: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.label.align

Comment: No, this only moves the labels, not the value on the axis

Comment: What exactly you mean? Axis value on the right position. Picture not described the problem.

Comment: Maybe using Mon through Sun is misleading, hopefully the other example clarifies the problem.

Comment: haha) Here, In Russia, a week starts on Monday. See second answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided the complete chart config, so I recommend using this one. Also pay attention on method [useUTC](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#useUTC) and you need to know that "[By default, echarts uses local timezone to formate time labels](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/11341#issuecomment-550346620)"

So I see this state of Chart by you data with offset -180:
[image]

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart'));
var chartData = [
  [1608534000000, 3],
  [1608537600000, 5],
  [1608541200000, 2],
  [1608544800000, 0],
  [1608548400000, 1],
];

var option = {
  tooltip: {},
  xAxis: {
    type: 'time',
    data: ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00'],
    splitNumber: 24,
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [{
    name: "Niederschlag",
    type: "bar",
    data: chartData,
    barWidth: '100%',
  }],
  useUTC: false,
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.9.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart" style="width: 1024px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid you still didn't get the point. You example shows the same issue: the bar is start at the half hour, not the full hour.